# Why is this element not starting at the top of its parent element?

Tags: html, css, drupal

On [this page](http://brainfx.evermight.net/?q=node/7), why is .section not sitting at the top of #content?

I asked some friends, and they don't know either.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the lack of details.  I thought to pull in all the html/css would be too much, so I didn't.  I was hoping the page would be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite the disaster

(`.tabs { display:none; }` or .tabs `{ float: left; }`) and
`#node-7 .field-item.even p { float:right; }`

Comment: Thanks - yup, lots of elements from Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've set `#content` to `display: inline; float: left;` on line 56 of `layout.css`.

Comment: Thanks Jezen, but this didn't work either.  I should have said I tried in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A friend figured out that there were 2 elements nested inside .content that were being put there by Drupal, that was causing the extra space at the top of #content.  The wierd thing is, they have to be removed together, in order for the space to go away.